# Finding time ranges from time point data in r

Tags: r

I'm using r to work on a dataset that lists different actions performed by different users, ranked in chronological order, such as this:

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ujzs.png)

How would I go about creating a list of the time periods between each user taking their first and last action?

Comment: Do not post images.  They can't be copied and pasted into R.  Use `dput(x)` where x is your input.

Comment: Sorry, poorly explained. My data is already in R, I just put that table together in MS Office to try and explain the situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
# generate data
set.seed(1000)
df <- data.frame(Time = sort(sample(seq(c(ISOdate(2017,3,20)), by = "min", length.out = 150), 9)),
                 User = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3), 
                 Action = rep(1:3, times = 3),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# get time between first and last action
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(User) %>%
   summarise(time_spent = max(Time) - min(Time))
```